# Bundle not receiving on back pressed

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am passing an intent extra on back pressed like this:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent()
    .putExtra(Constants.FROM_PRELOGIN, true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    Log.wtf("TAG",""+RESULT_OK);
}
```

and I am trying to receive the extra in the previous activity as:-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    switch (requestCode)

    {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PUNCHCARD_ACTIVITY:{
            if (resultCode == PunchCardDetailActivity.RESULT_OK){
                isFromPrelogin =data.getExtras().getBoolean(Constants.FROM_PRELOGIN);
                Log.wtf("Tag","yoyoy");
                getOffersAndLocationsList();
            }
        }
        break;

       default:
       break;
    }
}
```

this is static field i created

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PUNCHCARD_ACTIVITY = -1;
```

The issue i am not receiving the value i guess because the log is not displayed!Please Help.Thank You!

Comment: Did you use startActivityForResult() to start the second activity?

Comment: thanks dude got it.I was launching the second activity using startActivity(intent).I changed it to startActivityForResult(intent,int) and it worked like a charm.Thanks